# Java using Criteria builder for complex query

Tags: java, spring, criteria-api

I'm using Spring Boot 2.0, JPA, Hibernate 5 in my server project.

I'm struggling trying to convert this SQL query:

```
@Query("SELECT d FROM Document d  WHERE d.type='SALES_ORDER' AND d.status='PENDING' AND d.store.id=:storeId AND (SELECT COUNT(row) FROM DocumentRow row JOIN ProductAvailability pa ON (pa.productCode=row.productCode AND pa.productType=row.productType) WHERE row.document.id=d.id AND pa.qtyOnHand-pa.qtyAllocated < row.qty)=0")
```

to criteria. I'm using [RSQL](https://github.com/jirutka/rsql-parser) and for that I need to have a class like this:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Log4j2
public class DocumentRsqlSpecification<Document> implements Specification<Document>, RsqlSpecificationInterface<Document> {

     @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Document> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {


            Predicate onlySalesOrders = builder.equal(getPath(root, "type"), DocumentType.SALES_ORDER.toString());
        Predicate onlyPendingOrders = builder.equal(getPath(root, "status"), DocumentStatus.PENDING.toString());
        Predicate storePredicate = builder.equal(getPath(root, "store.id"), StoreContext.getCurrentStoreId());


        //(SELECT COUNT(row) FROM DocumentRow row JOIN ProductAvailability pa ON (pa.productCode=row.productCode AND pa.productType=row.productType) WHERE row.document.id=d.id AND pa.qtyOnHand-pa.qtyAllocated < row.qty)=0
        CriteriaQuery criteriaSubQuery = builder.createQuery(Long.class);
        Root subquery = criteriaSubQuery.from(DocumentRow.class);
        Selection row = subquery.alias("row");
        Join joinWithProductAvailability = subquery.join("product", JoinType.INNER);
        Selection productAvailability = joinWithProductAvailability.alias("pa");
        joinWithProductAvailability.on(
                builder.and(
                        //condition 1
                        builder.equal(getPath(subquery, "row.productCode"), getPath(subquery, "pa.productCode")),
                        //condition 2
                        builder.equal(getPath(subquery, "row.productType"), getPath(subquery, "pa.productType"))
                )
        );
        criteriaSubQuery.where(
                builder.and(
                        //filter on document id
                        builder.equal(getPath(subquery, "row.document.id"), getPath(root, "d.id")),
                        //filter on qty
                        builder.lessThanOrEqualTo(getPath(subquery, "pa.qtyOnHand-pa.qtyAllocated"), getPath(subquery, "row.qty"))
                ));
        Predicate subqueryPredicate = builder.equal(builder.count(subquery.get("id")), 0);


        propertyPredicate = builder.and(onlySalesOrders, onlyPendingOrders, storePredicate, subqueryPredicate);

       return propertyPredicate;

}
```

Unfortunately I don't understand how to create the subquery

```
(SELECT COUNT(row) FROM DocumentRow row JOIN ProductAvailability pa ON (pa.productCode=row.productCode AND pa.productType=row.productType) WHERE row.document.id=d.id AND row.product.id IS NOT NULL AND pa.qtyOnHand-pa.qtyAllocated < row.qty)=0
```

These are relevant model classes:

ProductAvailability:

```
public class ProductAvailability extends AbstractEntity {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "project_id", updatable = false)
    private Project project;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductUriDeserializer.class)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @NotNull(message = "{productavailability.product.missing}")
    @Any(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, metaDef = "ProductStockDef", metaColumn = @Column(name = "productGroup"), optional = false)
    @AnyMetaDef(name = "ProductStockDef", metaType = "string", idType = "long", metaValues = {
            @MetaValue(value = "OL", targetEntity = OphthalmicLens.class), @MetaValue(value = "F", targetEntity = Frame.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "CL", targetEntity = ContactLens.class), @MetaValue(value = "GP", targetEntity = GenericProduct.class)})
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", updatable = false)
    private Product product;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
    private ProductType productType;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productManufacturer;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String productDescription;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String productCode;

    @NotNull(message = "{productavailability.store.missing}")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", updatable = false)
    private Store store;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long qtyOnHand = 0;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long qtyAllocated = 0;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long qtyOnSalesOrders = 0;

    @NotNull
    @ColumnDefault("0")
    @Min(value = 0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private long qtyOnPurchaseOrders = 0;

    @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BIGINT(20) AS (qtyOnHand-qtyOnSalesOrders-qtyAllocated+qtyOnPurchaseOrders)")
    private long availability;

    private Instant firstPurchaseDate;

    private Instant lastPurchaseDate;

    private Instant firstSalesDate;

    private Instant lastSalesDate;

    //MAUC (moving average unit cost)
    @Min(value = 0)
    private BigDecimal averagePurchasePrice;

    @Min(value = 0)
    private BigDecimal lastPurchasePrice;

    //MAUP (moving average unit price)
    @Min(value = 0)
    private BigDecimal averageSalesPrice;

    @Min(value = 0)
    private BigDecimal lastSalesPrice;

}
```

and DocumentRow:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class DocumentRow extends AbstractEntity {

    @NotNull
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Document document;


    @Column(length = 30)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ProductType productType;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = ProductUriDeserializer.class)
    @Any(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, metaDef = "ProductDocumentRowDef", metaColumn = @Column(name = "productGroup"))
    @AnyMetaDef(name = "ProductDocumentRowDef", metaType = "string", idType = "long", metaValues = {@MetaValue(value = "OL", targetEntity = OphthalmicLens.class),
            @MetaValue(value = "F", targetEntity = Frame.class), @MetaValue(value = "CL", targetEntity = ContactLens.class), @MetaValue(value = "GP", targetEntity = GenericProduct.class)})
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(length = 50)
    private String productCode;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @NotBlank
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    // Reference to another document row (order/ddt/)
    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int qty = 1;

    @NotNull
    @Min(value = 0)
    @ColumnDefault("0.000")
    @Column(nullable = false, scale = 3, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(13,3)")
    private BigDecimal unitPrice = BigDecimal.ZERO;

}
```

and Product that is not mapped to a concrete table: in fact I've several classes that extends Products that are mapped to their own tables.

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class Product extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50, updatable = false)
    private String searchKey;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 50)
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String sku;


    @Size(min = 9, max = 30)
    @Column(nullable = true, length = 30)
    private String barcode;

    @NotBlank
    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String manufacturer;

    @Size(max = 255)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(scale = 3, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(13,3)")
    private BigDecimal purchasePrice;

    //vat excluded
    @Column(scale = 3, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(13,3)")
    private BigDecimal salesPrice;

    private BigDecimal taxRate;
}
```

I think I've some problems in my criteria. First of all I do not have a property where to lay on for the JOIN clause: in fact I do that JOIN using the condition ON.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: how are DocumentRow and ProductAvailability entity classes related in your JPA model? JPA supports joins using defined relationship with additional ON condition, like `DocumentRow row join row.productAvailability pa on (additional condition)`. For *-to-many relationships in Criteria query use plural joins, like `CollectionJoin`, `SetJoin` and so on

Comment: @AlexSalauyou I added the model detail. In fact I've not a property I can use to make the JOIN but I need to use a couple of properties to identify how to make the JOIN.